# ::before adding content on top instead of before the element

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to get the ">" point to the links, but using the :before, it appears on top for some reason.
Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance.

```css
ul{
 position: fixed;
 left: 1em;
}
li{
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}
li:before{
 content: "> ";
 color: #333;
}
li:hover:before:{
 color: hotpink;
}
a{
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 color: transparent;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
a:hover{
 transform: scale(1.1);
 color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Favourites</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `display` for your `a` tags is set to `block`. You can change this to `inline` or `inline-block`, or remove display as `inline` is the default for anchors, to get the results you were looking for:

```
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    color: transparent;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

**or**

```
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: transparent;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ::before content is behaving like a block. To do what you're asking, I'd absolutely position the ::before, like this:

```
li:before{
    content: "> ";
    color: #333;
    **top: 0px;
    left: -20px;
    position: absolute;**
}
```

And, relatively position the li, so that the ::before content positions relative to it, like this:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    **position: relative;**
}
```